# MySQL 8 database crash recovery

Tags: mysql-8.0

My dev SQL server crashed last night and would not restart. The error is:

```
[ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
```

I tried the classic "start with innodb_force_recovery=1" but that has 0 effect (also removed tried =2 without much success. I also tried removing the ibdata and ib logfiles: it won't start either.

I'm really surprised that these "standard" methods do not work for something that is a mere crash ... but evils is often in the details as we know.

So the last option I tried is re-creating the tables in the database and then replacing the .idb files that are automatically generated with the ones from the crashed server.

The positive is that the MySQL database starts ... but when I want to see the content of the tables I have an error message saying:

```
Error Code: 1812. Tablespace is missing for table <table>.
```

I feel I'm nearly there ... any help or suggestion would be welcomed.

Many thanks - Chris

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/ - more related to management (and potential recovery) of a database than programming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/ would be a better forum.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody gets this error while trying to restore mysql database from ibd file...
The issue on my side was just permissions and since I'm new to Linux(Ubuntu) I didn't know the commands. Just right click the corresponding ibd file > properties > select read and write from the 'Other Access' dropdown and I also checked allow executing file as program checkbox and it worked.